# Site is not opening after setting production mode Magento2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, production-mode

I set mode as production, after that my website gone down,

Is there any setting to be done? All css and js are showing 504 gateway error.

What is the reason for it?

Comment: did you checked Magento logs and reports?

Comment: Yes, no error logs

Comment: Please try `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento cache:flush` and check server logs also server credentials like ram, memory limit. You may have an issue with memory limit

Comment: Check php error logs in your server.

Comment: check server access log and error log

Comment: yes, checked no errors in log files.